# find all rows whose one column belongs to the same value and also another column satisfy a condition on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find all rows whose one column belongs to the same value and also satisfy a condition on SQL server 2008.

Table1:

```
       col1    col2 
       100     0
       100     1
       100     1
       200     0
       200     0
       200     0
       300     0
       300     0
       200     0
```

I need to get the rows that all its col2 = 0 for the same col1.

Here, I expect

```
           col1    col2 
           200     0
           200     0
           200     0
           300     0
           300     0
           300     0
```

Because all col2 is 0 for **col1 = 200 and col1 = 300**

```
   SELECT *
   FROM table1 as a
   where a.col2  = 0    # but, how to say col1 belong to the same value ?
```

Thx!

Comment: you mean u dont need the col1 value 100

Comment: I'm assuming your last row of the starting set (or the result set) has a typo for `col1` (ie, number of `200`s/`300`s doesn't match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the result for a *group of rows*, you could use grouping, e.g. like this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
HAVING SUM(col2) = 0
;
```

That would give you all [distinct] `col1` values whose `col2` totals are 0. That assumes, of course, that `SUM` is applicable in this situation – in particular, that `col2` is not `bit` and that `col2` can't have negative values. If you really mean to check for 0 as a specific value for the rows to have (or not to have), you could use a different aggregate function:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(col2, 0)) = 0
;
```

The above query would count non-0 values of `col2` in every group of `col1` and return only those `col1` values where the counts are 0.

Finally, if you really need to return detail rows rather than distinct `col1` values, you could use the above query's result as a derived table and filter the source table on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT col1
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY col1
  HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(col2, 0)) = 0
) AS filter
ON table1.col1 = filter.col1
;
```

However, there's another, potentially more efficient, way to do the same with the help of *window aggregation*, like this:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
FROM (
  SELECT *, cnt = COUNT(NULLIF(col2, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)
  FROM table1
) AS s
WHERE cnt = 0
;
```

The counts in the above query would be returned *alongside detail data*, and the outer query would just be filtering on them to ultimately produce only rows that had the counts of 0. The difference is, this method references the source table just once, which may result in a more efficient query plan than the previous method.

Answer (score 1):

From SQLServer 2005 we can use the `EXCEPT` keyword, that is the opposite of `UNION` e.g. it remove the row of the second query from the resultset of the first one, in this case

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  a.col2  = 0 
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, 0
FROM   table1 as a
WHERE  a.col2  <> 0
```

But `EXCEPT` return only the distinct rows, so maybe the `NOT EXISTS` version will be better

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table1 t2
                   WHERE  t1.col1 = t2.col1
                     AND  t2.col2 <> 0)
```

Comment: The OP hasn't listed all possible values for `col2`, so I'd hesitate to look for a specific value to knockout, in preference for using the value I do know about...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query:

```
select col1,col2 from samp a
where not exists (select 1 from samp
                            where col1 = a.col1
                and col2 <> a.col2)
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Of course, if there's a set of `col1` values that all have the same matching non-`0` value, this will return those as well.  What one condition can you add to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether I understood your question correctly.
Please see the solution.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (col1 int,col2 int)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(100,0),
(100,1),
(100,1),
(200,0),
(200,0),
(200,0),
(300,0),
(300,0),
(200,0)

SELECT  A.*
FROM    @TABLE A    
JOIN    (   
        SELECT col1 FROM @table WHERE col2 = 0
        GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) lU 
ON      A.col1 = LU.col1
WHERE   A.col2 = 0
```

### [image]

**Edit**: Modified SQL given.

```
SELECT  * FROM @table
WHERE   col1 IN
        (
        SELECT  A.col1
        FROM    (
                SELECT      col1,COUNT(*) [Count]
                FROM        @table 
                GROUP BY    col1 
                HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1) A
        JOIN    (
                SELECT      col1,COUNT(*) [Count]
                FROM        @table WHERE col2 = 0
                GROUP BY    col1 
                HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1) B
        ON      A.col1 = B.col1
        AND     A.Count = B.Count
        )
```

[image]

Comment: This won't work in cases where there's multiple `0`-value columns alongside columns valued as something else (ie, change on of the `(100, 1)` rows to be `(100, 0)`), which is likely for the OP's dataset.  This is a nicely formatted answer, showing you've done work _and_ tested it (you'd be surprised how many people don't ever bother) ... but it only works for the listed specific case, and not the likely general case.  You can't use this _exact_ form, but there are some close versions available.

Comment: I am still not sure about what specifically the user want, I thought he will give some explanation when he see this answer.

Comment: The question is asking for all rows where, for a given `col1`, all `col2` values are `0`.  Your current query fails (returns incorrect results) if there is more than one `col2 = 0` row and at least one where `col2 <> 2` is true.  Try adding rows where `col1` is `400`, with the `col2` values the opposite of the `100` rows (so, two `0` rows, one `1` row).  The end results should be the same as you have currently.  Oh, and the outer `WHERE` condition should be unnecessary.